# Multiple Column Sort Using Angular JS

Tags: angularjs, sorting

I have a table with the columns `Name`,`Category`,`DocumentName` and `Date_generated`.
`DocumentName` should be a secondary sort column, so for example if I sort by Name in `desc` order, documentname should always be in ascending order. Sort should happen on table header click.

In the header I have mentioned the column names as follows:

```
ng-click="orderByFieldName=['name','doc_name']; sortOrder=!sortOrder"
```

and in `ng-repeat` as `orderBy:orderByFieldName:sortOrder`

But now both are sorted in either ascending or descending order together.. How can we have a default sort order for doc-Name alone?

Comment: i am having question that "documentname should always be in ascending order" what does it mean ?? if you are providing documentname as sort then it will change according to the click

Comment: ex: i have 5names as 'Ashok' and 5other names as 'Rathod' and Ashok has documentname A,C,D,E,B then my table should display rows as 'Ashok A','Ashok B','Ashok C','Ashok D','Ashok E','Rathod X'....

Answer (score 0):

```
This was achieved using different sortOrder for the fields and based on current sortOrder we toggle the doc_name as shown below:

$scope.customSort = function () {

            var docName = 'doc_name';
            if (!$scope.sortOrder) {
                docName = '-doc_name';
            }

            if ($scope.orderByFieldName == 1) {
                if ($scope.sortFlag == 1) {
                    $scope.staffNameSortOrder = !$scope.staffNameSortOrder;
                }
                else {
                    $scope.staffNameSortOrder = false;
                    docName = 'doc_name';
                    $scope.sortFlag = 1;
                }

                $scope.orderByFieldName = ['staff_name', docName];
                $scope.sortOrder = $scope.staffNameSortOrder;
            }
else if ($scope.orderByFieldName == 3) {
                if ($scope.sortFlag == 3) {
                    $scope.docNameSortOrder = !$scope.docNameSortOrder;
                }
                else {
                    $scope.docNameSortOrder = false;
                    $scope.sortFlag = 3;
                }
                $scope.orderByFieldName = ['doc_name'];
                $scope.sortOrder = $scope.docNameSortOrder; 

            }
}

In the ng-repeat you can add orderBy:orderByFieldName:sortOrder
```